# .NET C++: How to bind parameters to a delegate to create a new a zero-parameter delegate?

Tags: .net, parameters, delegates, c++-cli, bind

Is there any way to bind parameters to a delegate to create a new zero-parameter delegate?

Something like:

```
delegate void FnDelegate(int id, String^ name);
void Fn(int id, String^ name);

Delegate^ del = <some-function-name>(gcnew FnDelegate(&Fn), 1, "Name");
```

I notice that Form::Invoke probably uses some similar mechanism, so there MUST be some facility for this:

```
delegate void FnDelegate(int id, String^ name);
Invoke(gcnew FnDelegate(&Fn), 1, "Name");
```

Right now, I have to do something extremely awkward like this (for each function!):

```
void Fn(int id, String^ name);

ref class FnWrapper
{
public:
   int     id;
   String^ name;

   void Execute()
   {
      Fn(id, name);
   }
};

delegate void VoidDelegate();
Delegate^ CreateFnDelegate(int id, String^ name)
{
   FnWrapper^ Wrapper = gcnew FnWrapper;
   Wrapper->id = id;
   Wrapper->name = name;
   return gcnew VoidDelegate(Wrapper, &FnWrapper::Execute);
}
```

There's got to be a more elegant way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ has several mechanisms for this, `boost::bind` became `std::bind`, and now we have lambdas.  They don't work with managed types though.  Hopefully a future version of the C++/CLI compiler will add lambda functionality, until then your approach with a helper object is pretty much it (but you can genericize it to reduce code duplication.  Both storing the function to call as a delegate, and using templates for the parameter types, can make this more reusable.)

Note that the nicer methods pretty much simply automate construction of the helper object, there isn't really any known ways to do the guts much differently.

`Form::Invoke` simply sticks all the parameters in an `array<Object^>` and uses reflection when invoking... you can do that too, but it is a major performance hit.

```
ref class AnyDelegateWrapper
{
public:
   System::Delegate^ target;
   array<System::Object^>^ args;

   void Execute()
   {
      target->DynamicInvoke(args);
   }
};

System::Action^ mg_bind(System::Delegate^ d, ... array<System::Object^>^ args)
{
    AnyDelegateWrapper^ w = gcnew AnyDelegateWrapper();
    w->target = d;
    w->args = args;
    return gcnew System::Action(w, &AnyDelegateWrapper::Execute);
}

Action^ del = mg_bind(gcnew FnDelegate(&Fn), 1, "Name");
```

Comment: "Form::Invoke simply sticks all the parameters in an array<Object^> and uses reflection when invoking... you can do that too, but it is a major performance hit."

How do I do this? I'm not concerned with performance.

Comment: @user3215177: I added a code snippet, but it isn't compiled or tested.  Let me know how it works.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. Works perfectly. KISS principle - nice, clean and generic. Didn't copy and paste, but wrote the code I needed based on your code.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do here is called variable capture.

In C#, you would do this by defining an inline delegate, which would do the variable capture for you:

```
Action<int, string> delegateWithParams = ...
Action delegateWithoutParams1 = delegate { delegateWithParams(7, "foo"); };
// or if you like lambda syntax:
Action delegateWithoutParams2 = () => delegateWithParams(7, "foo");
```

C++/CLI doesn't have inline delegates or lambdas, so you have to do the variable capture manually. Here's a class I wrote to help with the variable capture and my test program.

If you ever look at decompiled C# code, you'll see that the C# compiler is basically doing the same thing when it does variable capture: it creates a helper class to store the captured variables, and the delegate without parameters is defined on that class to call the delegate with parameters.

```
void SomeMethod(int i, String^ s)
{
    Debug::WriteLine("SomeMethod was called with integer {0} and string '{1}'", i, s);
}

generic<typename T1, typename T2>
public ref class VariableCapture
{
private:
    Action<T1,T2>^ delegateWithParams;
    T1 item1;
    T2 item2;

    VariableCapture(Action<T1,T2>^ delegateWithParams, T1 item1, T2 item2)
    {
        this->delegateWithParams = delegateWithParams;
        this->item1 = item1;
        this->item2 = item2;
    }

    void RunDelegate()
    {
        this->delegateWithParams(item1, item2);
    }

public:
    static Action^ Capture(
        Action<T1,T2>^ delegateWithParams, T1 item1, T2 item2)
    {
        VariableCapture<T1,T2>^ capture = 
            gcnew VariableCapture<T1,T2>(delegateWithParams, item1, item2);
        return gcnew Action(capture, &VariableCapture<T1,T2>::RunDelegate);
    }
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Action<int, String^>^ delegateWithParams = 
        gcnew Action<int, String^>(&SomeMethod);

    Action^ delegateWithoutParams = 
        VariableCapture<int, String^>::Capture(delegateWithParams, 7, "foo");

    delegateWithoutParams();
}
```

Output:

> SomeMethod was called with integer 7 and string 'foo'

- Once `delegateWithoutParams` is created, you don't need to keep references to the capture object or the delegate with parameters: They'll be kept alive by the references in `delegateWithoutParams`.
- You will need to write a version of VariableCapture for each number of parameters, as well as separate versions for `Action<>` vs. `Func<>`.
- Since this is (basically) the same thing that C# does, this will be as performant as doing it in C#. (No reflection overhead.)